# Export-CSV only returns first element

Tags: xml, powershell, foreach, formatting, export-to-csv

So I have this script that takes data from an xml, specifically the Name of the machines and then a list of the id numbers for each. I am able to get each into variables but when I try to list all of the id's only the first element for each shows up. I thought Export-CSV -Append could have solved this but so far nothing.

```
$path="C:\Users\Desktop\DataIDs"
$xmls = Get-ChildItem $path\* -Recurse | where {$_.Name -like '*DataIDX*'} 

$results = New-Object psobject

ForEach ($xml in $xmls) {
    [xml]$results = Get-Content $xml
    $Name = $results.Benchmark.TestResult.target
    $VID1 = @($results.Benchmark.TestResult.'rule-result' | where {$_.result -eq 'fail'}).Version | Sort-Object
    $VID = $VID1 | Out-String

    ForEach ($id in $VID) {
        $results | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Name -Value $id
        }
}

$results | Export-Csv $path\results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
Remove-Variable results
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way you append the member gives it all up:

```
Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Name -Value $id
```

You are always appending the same member. So the other appends are throwing "the member is already there and cannot write to that property" or something like that.

ps. My bad, I didn't read the original question properly. I've edited the answer to explain it properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an Array to store all the `$results` objects, you are overwriting it every time...

**EDIT:** Also another problem I see is that your `$VID` is a String Object, you cannot iterate a string object, you will get chars... which I believe is not what you need, remove the `Out-String` and try again

Try this:

```
$path="C:\Users\Desktop\DataIDs"
$xmls = Get-ChildItem $path\* -Recurse | where {$_.Name -like '*DataIDX*'} 

$resultsArray = @()
ForEach ($xml in $xmls) {
    [xml]$results = Get-Content $xml
    $Name = $results.Benchmark.TestResult.target
    $VID1 = @($results.Benchmark.TestResult.'rule-result' | where {$_.result -eq 'fail'}).Version | Sort-Object
    $VID = $VID1 

    ForEach ($id in $VID) {
        $results | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $Name -Value $id
        }
$resultsArray += $results
}

$resultsArray | Export-Csv $path\results.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
Remove-Variable results
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reposes, tried this and im getting "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" but what your saying sounds right